# Google charts grouping

Tags: javascript, charts, grouping

I added a dates to rows in google charts.

27-12-2011,
01-01-2012,
23-01-2012,
etc..

I want to display that dates between Dec 2011, Jan 2012 and Feb 2012 but chart displays all dates. It doesn't group them. How to group them?

Comment: Can you display your code ? It difficult to help you without

Answer (score 0):

You can add another column to the table with your aggregation category, such as `month` or `year`. Then you can use the grouping feature from the `google.visualization.data.group()` by average, sum, or some other aggregating function.

You should check this the [Google Visualization API reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group).